# Memory is rising too fast in high rates

Tags: c, performance, server, embedded, memory-efficient

I'm working on a simple proxy application on an embedded system, and I'm having some issues related to memory management.

**The concept:**

```
recv_daemon() // thread
{
    // recv packets from tcp
    // allocates node and push to queue
}

recv()
{
    // wait until queue is not empty
    // pull message from queue and frees it
}

send()
{
    // send message with tcp
}

main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        recv(buffer);
        send(buffer);
    }
}
```

so I think it's pretty easy to understand.

1. the daemon constantly receiving packets from the network
2. the daemon push a message to the queue
3. the main function calls the `recv()` function who pulls a message from the queue
4. the main function sends the packet received to the other side
5. repeat 3 and 4

**The issue:**

to test the application, I tried to send packets in a high rate (but still a rate that the hardware should be ok with).

The problem is that for each packet that the daemon pushes to the queue, it allocates memory (which makes sense).

Because of that fact, and the fact that the send function is taking a bit time, there is much more allocations than frees, because the `recv()` function (which pulls messages) gets called less than the `recv_daemon()` pushes.

Which makes the memory **fly up**.

I tried to make the send a little more efficient and it did help a little but not enough.

I tried commenting out the `send()` and there was no problem.

Problem is that the couple of functions that send have, must be there and there is no way no make it more efficient than it is (even it there was, it wouldn't be enough).

I'm wondering if there is a solution to this problem. Even maybe in the design?

BTW, I'm using a thread cause I wanna handle messages that are not data (like pings).

Comment: Have you tried anything to synchronize the main thread with the deamon? Something like serial communication flow control, which asks the sender to slow down as soon as a guard _hi-water_ threshold is reached, and tells it everything it's ok as soon as a _low-water_ threshold is reached.

Comment: For further pieces of advice I'm afraid you will have to share more details about the implementation of the functions and data exchange timing.

Comment: i thought about doing something like that, but isn't that the same?
when the sender will stop using the tcp_recv function, the packets will just all wait in the kernel itself and will still take memory? am i wrong?
unfortunately i can't share the implementation, but i'm only asking design-wise,
not how to make the functions more efficient

Comment: Packets that remain unread (meaning not received by functions such as `recv()`) make the TCP stack limit in turn the throughput with the remote peer (are you familiar with TCP window size?). Of course the whole system must be fast enough to avoid remote socket closure due to inactivity.

Comment: that actually really helped, i haven't thought about it.
so theoretically if i limit the queue capacity to let's say 200 messages, and when it reaches 200 the thread stop receiving until the queue has some free space.
will it be good enough, or can it be too dangerous for performance?

Comment: It depends on too many factors I cannot guess. If you have traffic peaks that make your heap explode, it will probably solve your issue by postponing the effort. If you cannot manage "normal" traffic (data exchange is continuous) it will end up making the remote peer disconnect due to inactivity from your side.

Comment: i see, so the only REAL solution is to make the code efficient enough so the malloc and free will happen very closely and the memory won't go up?(in case the traffic is always fast and not by peaks)

Comment: Without seeing the _real_ code how are we supposed to advise!?  But if your send _sink_ is slower than your receive _source_, then you can never "catch-up".  If the data is streaming the sink must be as fast or faster than the source, otherwise if the data comes in bursts giving the sink time to catch up, then the buffer/queue must have sufficient capacity to accommodate the "high-tide" of incoming data - that simple.  The simple solution is to control the speed of the input by not acknowledging incoming packets until you have sufficient buffer available to receive them.

Comment: You might consider "zero-copy" semantics; rather then copying to a queue, then copying off the queue into `buffer` and free'ing, instead use a queue of pointers and deallocate _after_ `send()`.  Still won't help if the send sink is slower.

Comment: So basically you are processing data slower than you are receiving it. What do you want the program to do? Maybe say what you want the program to do and then maybe we can help you make it do that.

Comment: Indeed, you have a big pipe filling a basin with a small drain.   You'll need to either block the input when the number of queued items gets too high, or just start discarding inputs and let resend logic at the sender try again later.